# Problem Creating dll library file from various methods in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dll

[sereenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rfNH.png)

1. I have a problem creating dll file.
2. Errors of the problems are shown in picture.
3. Anyone who knows the solution of the problems, help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Put your LoadColumn function inside of your class

Answer (score 0):

Note that in C#, methods and variables must be declared and defined within a struct or class. For more information on program structure in C#, see the General Structure of a C# Program article. To fix this error, rewrite your code such that all methods and fields are contained within either a struct or a class.

Reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116#:~:text=A%20namespace%20cannot%20directly%20contain,see%20the%20namespace%20keyword%20article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116#:%7E:text=A%20namespace%20cannot%20directly%20contain,see%20the%20namespace%20keyword%20article).